# How to determine the sides of this triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given:

```
ABC is right triangle
CH - height of hypotenuse
ABC is similar to the triangle ACH and CBH
The area of ABC = 30
AB = 13
```

Find:

```
CH, AC BC
```

So far all I was able to is to find that CH = 60/13

```
S = AB * CH / 2
30 = 13 * CH / 2
CH = 30 * 2 / 13 => CH = 60/13
```

But now I have no idea how to fin AC and BC . I thought applying the Pythagoras theorem however, I don't see how I can do this with the current knowledge. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This problem becomes easy if you recognize $169$ (i.e., $13^2$) as the sum of two squares.

Comment: My LATEX isn't working think so sorry cordially.

Comment: Hint is should  be BC  so now BC is $60/13$ now use Pythagoras theorem to get the hypotenuse and again 1/2.hypotenuse.CH=30 so now You got all the the things CH,AC,BC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that  $Ac^2+BC^2=AB^2=13^2=169$ by Phythagorous.
Note that the equation  $x^2+y^2=169$ has only one integer solution which is  $x=12$ and  $y=5$ ( or  $x=5$  and  $y=12$) .
Thus  $AC=5$  and  $BC=12$ (or  $AC=12$  and  $BC=5$).

Comment: You can't just assume that $x$ and $y$ are integers. However, we know that the $xy/2$ must equal the area of ABC, so $xy=60$, and the only positive solution pair to the simultaneous equations $x^2 + y^2=169$ and  $xy=60$ is $(5, 12)$.